# can't execute a gradle wrapper script through a PHP script

Tags: php, android, linux, gradle, command-line-interface

I'll try to be brief with what I'm trying to accomplish.

What I'm trying to do here, is that I want to make a webApp that automates the build of android apps (APKs) based on user input.

I'm running a CLI Ubuntu Linux server (18.04.1), that has a LAMP stack installed on

For apache :

```
$ apache2 -v 
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2021-06-18T11:06:22
```

For PHP :

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.21 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2021 16:09:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

For MySQL

```
$ sudo mysql -v -u mysql_username -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 48
Server version: 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

I have made a directory  ( `/var/www/my_webapp.com/` ) where my webApp resides and it is as the following:

```
.
├── build.sh
├── Source
│   ├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── gradle
│   ├── .gradle
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── local.properties
│   └── settings.gradle
└── test.php
```

the `build.sh` script is responsible for calling the gradle wrapper and starting the build process, and it is as the following:

```
cd /var/www/my_webapp.com/Source/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

The `Source` directory is a folder that contains the android app source code we want to build and compile to an APK.

and last but not least, `test.php` script that issues command for the bash script (`build.sh`) to build the APK. and it is as the following :

```
<?php
/**
 * Execute the given command by displaying console output live to the user.
 *  @param  string  cmd          :  command to be executed
 *  @return array   exit_status  :  exit status of the executed command
 *                  output       :  console output of the executed command
 */
function liveExecuteCommand($cmd) {

    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

    $old_directory = getcwd();
    chdir("Source/");

    $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

    $live_output     = "";
    $complete_output = "";

    echo "<pre>";
    while (!feof($proc)) {
        $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
        $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
        echo $live_output . "\n";
        @ flush();
    }
    echo "</pre>";

    pclose($proc);

    // get exit status
    preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $complete_output, $matches);

    chdir($old_directory);

    // return exit status and intended output
    return array ('exit_status'  => intval($matches[0]),
                    'output'       => str_replace("Exit status : " . $matches[0], '', $complete_output)
                );
}

$result = liveExecuteCommand(dirname(__FILE__) . '/build.sh');


if($result['exit_status'] === 0){
    echo "finished sucessfully. <br /> ";
} else {
    echo "finished with error: {$result['output']} <br /> ";
}
```

The problem is when I try to run the php script - `test.php` that is -, I get this error:

```
finished with error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create parent directory for lock file /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-bin/6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p/gradle-6.5-bin.zip.lck
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:43)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

And when I try to run the `build.sh` script manually in the terminal, it runs fine and generates the APK.

I don't know why gradle build script tries to create a directory in the path as it is shown in the previous error message, knoing that the build script resides on a completely different directory (`/var/www/my_webapp.com`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was a permissions issue, since the user who executes the script is `www-data` coming from Apache. So all I had to do was changing the owner of the directory recursively to `www-data` with the following command :

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data my_webapp.com/
```

And it worked fine.